# Java sequencer Listener

Tags: java, midi

I am programming a game in java, and tried to add music.
Im doing just this:

```
Sequencer sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
sequencer.open();
InputStream midiFile = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream( "/res/Popcorn.mid" ); 
sequencer.setSequence( MidiSystem.getSequence(midiFile) ); 
sequencer.start();
```

The Problem is, the file is not very small so its loading while the game already started.
So, is there anything like an sequencer listener, so i can wait until the sound finished loading?

Or when not, is there a way to programe one for my self?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that it's creating a delay?  Have you tried running this on its own thread?

Comment: Ill do tomorow :) thanks! But could you explain, why the thread is needed here? I mean, achtally i thaught when i dont do it with a thread, the programm wil wait until the sequence has loaded - but it seems to be inverted. Why?

Comment: MIDI sequences normally play in the background.  It hardly ever makes sense to start a tune, and then wait for that tune to complete before doing something else.

Comment: So i could du it like this: public static void main (){ Thread t = new Thread (this); abd in the run add the code above?

Answer (score 2):

You must add loading. For example: you run main class in new Thread. For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Thread() {
        public void run(){
            JFrame ... //frame with game
            //now you add text type "Please wait"

            Sequencer sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
            sequencer.open();
            InputStream midiFile = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream( "/res/Popcorn.mid" ); 
            sequencer.setSequence( MidiSystem.getSequence(midiFile) ); 
            sequencer.start(); 
            //Starting the game here

            //You must close this game at end
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }.start();
    while(true) { //this is slepping this program
        Thread.sleep(4096);
    }
```

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: No problem, by the way im not english to ;) but why you said i have to close the game? I mean, whatt matter ot das to the sequence? And, why the programm is just running ahead when i do it without a thread??

Comment: Can you upload this sound? I can't test it.

Comment: The game is starting, but the sound still hasnt loading. But my aim was that the main game waits, until the sound finished loading.